# fancyhead R-L direction switched in RTL languages on some pages

Tags: header-footer, hebrew

I use `fancyhead` with the switches `R` and `L`. When I write a document in an RTL language (with babel), sometime the R and L directions are switched.

I believe this has something to do with the text that happens to be at end of the page - if it's an RTL language, the directions are switched.

How can I solve this, i.e. is it possible to use 'absolute' directions for fancyhead?

Thanks!

Images:

A page with correct direction (English text at the end), followed by an incorrect one (Hebrew text at the end; the font of the page number itself is also changed):

[image]
[image]

MWE (just a bunch of random text):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[hebrew,english]{babel}
\selectlanguage{hebrew}
\usepackage{culmus}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[L]{\L{left}}
\fancyhead[R]{\L{right}}

\begin{document}
\L{ \Blindtext  }
 \L{
\Blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext

}
 \R{
אם לאחרונה לויקיפדיה לרפובליקה אחר, חפש גם דרכה בשפה פיסול. על המחשב מדויקים קרימינולוגיה שכל, זאת ערכים ומהימנה דת, מרצועת קצרמרים אם עזה. זאת ספינות ארכיאולוגיה בה, ב החלה ובמתן ביולי לוח. מתוך בישול מדריכים צ'ט אל, בה חשמל המשפט והנדסה רבה, שכל שונה בשפה הבקשה על.

תרבות פיסול מדינות תנך של, או נפלו אתנולוגיה האנציקלופדיה זכר. מלא או מוגש לתרום ממונרכיה, בקר פולנית יוצרים אנגלית דת, דת מיזם צילום מוסיקה שער. פיסול ניווט הבהרה בקר בה, עזה למנוע הראשי לאחרונה של. שתפו ניהול מה שער, על יוני והגולשים צעד, של ויש לציין הגרפים.

על שמו אקטואליה ביוטכנולוגיה, קולנוע ארכיאולוגיה מדע ב. שכל תיבת בשפה ויקימדיה או, מדעי אינו אדריכלות או כדי. עוד בה לשון המלצת בלשנות, ליום מיזם גם זאת. המלצת מונחונים אל צ'ט, גם אחרות מבוקשים ויקיפדיה מלא, ומדעים לעריכה היסטוריה אל קרן. ויש גם מאמר המלחמה משחקים, אם שער בישול ליצירתה, בארגז מיוחדים מה היא. שמות פיסיקה ארץ אם, בקלות ברוכים היא מה.

על שמו אקטואליה ביוטכנולוגיה, קולנוע ארכיאולוגיה מדע ב. שכל תיבת בשפה ויקימדיה או, מדעי אינו אדריכלות או כדי. עוד בה לשון המלצת בלשנות, ליום מיזם גם זאת. המלצת מונחונים אל צ'ט, גם אחרות מבוקשים ויקיפדיה מלא, ומדעים לעריכה היסטוריה אל קרן. ויש גם מאמר המלחמה משחקים, אם שער בישול ליצירתה, בארגז מיוחדים מה היא. שמות פיסיקה ארץ אם, בקלות ברוכים היא מה.
ערכים ומהימנה דת, מרצועת קצרמרים אם עזה. זאת ספינות ארכיאולוגיה בה, ב החלה ובמתן ביולי לוח. מתוך בישול מדריכים צ'ט אל, בה חשמל המשפט והנדסה רבה, שכל שונה בשפה הבקשה על.

תרבות פיסול מדינות תנך של, או נפלו אתנולוגיה האנציקלופדיה זכר. מלא או מוגש לתרום ממונרכיה, בקר פולנית יוצרים אנגלית דת, דת מיזם צילום מוסיקה שער. פיסול ניווט הבהרה בקר בה, עזה למנוע הראשי לאחרונה של. שתפו ניהול מה שער, על יוני והגולשים צעד, של ויש לציין הגרפים.

על שמו אקטואליה ביוטכנולוגיה, קולנוע ארכיאולוגיה מדע ב. שכל תיבת בשפה ויקימדיה או, מדעי אינו אדריכלות או כדי. עוד בה לשון המלצת בלשנות, ליום מיזם גם זאת. המלצת מונחונים אל צ'ט, גם אחרות מבוקשים ויקיפדיה מלא, ומדעים לעריכה היסטוריה אל קרן. ויש גם מאמר המלחמה משחקים, אם שער בישול ליצירתה, בארגז מיוחדים מה היא. שמות פיסיקה ארץ אם, בקלות ברוכים היא מה.

על שמו אקטואליה ביוטכנולוגיה, קולנוע ארכיאולוגיה מדע ב. שכל תיבת בשפה ויקימדיה או, מדעי אינו אדריכלות או כדי. עוד בה לשון המלצת בלשנות, ליום מיזם גם זאת. המלצת מונחונים אל צ'ט, גם אחרות מבוקשים ויקיפדיה מלא, ומדעים לעריכה היסטוריה אל קרן. ויש גם מאמר המלחמה משחקים, אם שער בישול ליצירתה, בארגז מיוחדים מה היא. שמות פיסיקה ארץ אם, בקלות ברוכים היא מה.ערכים ומהימנה דת, מרצועת קצרמרים אם עזה. זאת ספינות ארכיאולוגיה בה, ב החלה ובמתן ביולי לוח. מתוך בישול מדריכים צ'ט אל, בה חשמל המשפט והנדסה רבה, שכל שונה בשפה הבקשה על.

תרבות פיסול מדינות תנך של, או נפלו אתנולוגיה האנציקלופדיה זכר. מלא או מוגש לתרום ממונרכיה, בקר פולנית יוצרים אנגלית דת, דת מיזם צילום מוסיקה שער. פיסול ניווט הבהרה בקר בה, עזה למנוע הראשי לאחרונה של. שתפו ניהול מה שער, על יוני והגולשים צעד, של ויש לציין הגרפים.

על שמו אקטואליה ביוטכנולוגיה, קולנוע ארכיאולוגיה מדע ב. שכל תיבת בשפה ויקימדיה או, מדעי אינו אדריכלות או כדי. עוד בה לשון המלצת בלשנות, ליום מיזם גם זאת. המלצת מונחונים אל צ'ט, גם אחרות מבוקשים ויקיפדיה מלא, ומדעים לעריכה היסטוריה אל קרן. ויש גם מאמר המלחמה משחקים, אם שער בישול ליצירתה, בארגז מיוחדים מה היא. שמות פיסיקה ארץ אם, בקלות ברוכים היא מה.

על שמו אקטואליה ביוטכנולוגיה, קולנוע ארכיאולוגיה מדע ב. שכל תיבת בשפה ויקימדיה או, מדעי אינו אדריכלות או כדי. עוד בה לשון המלצת בלשנות, ליום מיזם גם זאת. המלצת מונחונים אל צ'ט, גם אחרות מבוקשים ויקיפדיה מלא, ומדעים לעריכה היסטוריה אל קרן. ויש גם מאמר המלחמה משחקים, אם שער בישול ליצירתה, בארגז מיוחדים מה היא. שמות פיסיקה ארץ אם, בקלות ברוכים היא מה.ערכים ומהימנה דת, מרצועת קצרמרים אם עזה. זאת ספינות ארכיאולוגיה בה, ב החלה ובמתן ביולי לוח. מתוך בישול מדריכים צ'ט אל, בה חשמל המשפט והנדסה רבה, שכל שונה בשפה הבקשה על.

תרבות פיסול מדינות תנך של, או נפלו אתנולוגיה האנציקלופדיה זכר. מלא או מוגש לתרום ממונרכיה, בקר פולנית יוצרים אנגלית דת, דת מיזם צילום מוסיקה שער. פיסול ניווט הבהרה בקר בה, עזה למנוע הראשי לאחרונה של. שתפו ניהול מה שער, על יוני והגולשים צעד, של ויש לציין הגרפים.

על שמו אקטואליה ביוטכנולוגיה, קולנוע ארכיאולוגיה מדע ב. שכל תיבת בשפה ויקימדיה או, מדעי אינו אדריכלות או כדי. עוד בה לשון המלצת בלשנות, ליום מיזם גם זאת. המלצת מונחונים אל צ'ט, גם אחרות מבוקשים ויקיפדיה מלא, ומדעים לעריכה היסטוריה אל קרן. ויש גם מאמר המלחמה משחקים, אם שער בישול ליצירתה, בארגז מיוחדים מה היא. שמות פיסיקה ארץ אם, בקלות ברוכים היא מה.

על שמו אקטואליה ביוטכנולוגיה, קולנוע ארכיאולוגיה מדע ב. שכל תיבת בשפה ויקימדיה או, מדעי אינו אדריכלות או כדי. עוד בה לשון המלצת בלשנות, ליום מיזם גם זאת. המלצת מונחונים אל צ'ט, גם אחרות מבוקשים ויקיפדיה מלא, ומדעים לעריכה היסטוריה אל קרן. ויש גם מאמר המלחמה משחקים, אם שער בישול ליצירתה, בארגז מיוחדים מה היא. שמות פיסיקה ארץ אם, בקלות ברוכים היא מה.ערכים ומהימנה דת, מרצועת קצרמרים אם עזה. זאת ספינות ארכיאולוגיה בה, ב החלה ובמתן ביולי לוח. מתוך בישול מדריכים צ'ט אל, בה חשמל המשפט והנדסה רבה, שכל שונה בשפה הבקשה על.

תרבות פיסול מדינות תנך של, או נפלו אתנולוגיה האנציקלופדיה זכר. מלא או מוגש לתרום ממונרכיה, בקר פולנית יוצרים אנגלית דת, דת מיזם צילום מוסיקה שער. פיסול ניווט הבהרה בקר בה, עזה למנוע הראשי לאחרונה של. שתפו ניהול מה שער, על יוני והגולשים צעד, של ויש לציין הגרפים.

על שמו אקטואליה ביוטכנולוגיה, קולנוע ארכיאולוגיה מדע ב. שכל תיבת בשפה ויקימדיה או, מדעי אינו אדריכלות או כדי. עוד בה לשון המלצת בלשנות, ליום מיזם גם זאת. המלצת מונחונים אל צ'ט, גם אחרות מבוקשים ויקיפדיה מלא, ומדעים לעריכה היסטוריה אל קרן. ויש גם מאמר המלחמה משחקים, אם שער בישול ליצירתה, בארגז מיוחדים מה היא. שמות פיסיקה ארץ אם, בקלות ברוכים היא מה.

על שמו אקטואליה ביוטכנולוגיה, קולנוע ארכיאולוגיה מדע ב. שכל תיבת בשפה ויקימדיה או, מדעי אינו אדריכלות או כדי. עוד בה לשון המלצת בלשנות, ליום מיזם גם זאת. המלצת מונחונים אל צ'ט, גם אחרות מבוקשים ויקיפדיה מלא, ומדעים לעריכה היסטוריה אל קרן. ויש גם מאמר המלחמה משחקים, אם שער בישול ליצירתה, בארגז מיוחדים מה היא. שמות פיסיקה ארץ אם, בקלות ברוכים היא מה.
 } 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a `\selectlanguage{}` in the header? Is XeLaTeX an option?

Comment: I don't see where I could add this, because inside the 'fancyhead' text it's already too late... 
I would rather stay with pdflatex.

Comment: Typesetting languages such as Hebrew is ***way*** easier with XeLaTeX than pdfLaTeX. I've added an example in case you are interested. (I don't have **cumulus** so I couldn't even begin to deal with the pdfLaTeX approach.) With XeLaTeX, you have **fontspec**, **polyglossia**, **bidi** and unicode is just built in.... Unless you are just typesetting a fragment of Hebrew once or twice in one document, you should really consider it. And I say this as somebody who is adamant that pdfLaTeX is *not* deprecated because it supports things you can't do with Xe/LuaLaTeX. (I still use only pdfLaTeX.)

Comment: Thank you. As I said in response to your answer below, this is a 'legacy' document so I cannot change the compiler at this stage...

Comment: Yes. I understand. I'll leave the example as it may be useful to others. But I'm sure somebody with **cumulus** will answer.

Comment: a trick `\fancyhead[L]{\L{left\hfill}}
\fancyhead[R]{\L{\hfill right}}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `babel` package defines a conditional to check whether you are in left-to-right mode or in right-to-left mode (it is true in the latter case). This is called `if@rl`. So you can just check that in your header definitions to cancel out the mirroring when switching to right-to-left mode:

```
\makeatletter
\fancyhead[L]{\if@rl\L{right}\else\L{left}\fi}
\fancyhead[R]{\if@rl\L{left}\else\L{right}\fi}
\makeatother
```

The complete code is then:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[hebrew,english]{babel}
\selectlanguage{hebrew}
\usepackage{culmus}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\makeatletter
\fancyhead[L]{\if@rl\L{right}\else\L{left}\fi}
\fancyhead[R]{\if@rl\L{left}\else\L{right}\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\L{ \Blindtext  }
 \L{
\Blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext

}
 \R{
אם לאחרונה לויקיפדיה לרפובליקה אחר, חפש גם דרכה בשפה פיסול. על המחשב מדויקים קרימינולוגיה שכל, זאת ערכים ומהימנה דת, מרצועת קצרמרים אם עזה. זאת ספינות ארכיאולוגיה בה, ב החלה ובמתן ביולי לוח. מתוך בישול מדריכים צ'ט אל, בה חשמל המשפט והנדסה רבה, שכל שונה בשפה הבקשה על.

תרבות פיסול מדינות תנך של, או נפלו אתנולוגיה האנציקלופדיה זכר. מלא או מוגש לתרום ממונרכיה, בקר פולנית יוצרים אנגלית דת, דת מיזם צילום מוסיקה שער. פיסול ניווט הבהרה בקר בה, עזה למנוע הראשי לאחרונה של. שתפו ניהול מה שער, על יוני והגולשים צעד, של ויש לציין הגרפים.

על שמו אקטואליה ביוטכנולוגיה, קולנוע ארכיאולוגיה מדע ב. שכל תיבת בשפה ויקימדיה או, מדעי אינו אדריכלות או כדי. עוד בה לשון המלצת בלשנות, ליום מיזם גם זאת. המלצת מונחונים אל צ'ט, גם אחרות מבוקשים ויקיפדיה מלא, ומדעים לעריכה היסטוריה אל קרן. ויש גם מאמר המלחמה משחקים, אם שער בישול ליצירתה, בארגז מיוחדים מה היא. שמות פיסיקה ארץ אם, בקלות ברוכים היא מה.

על שמו אקטואליה ביוטכנולוגיה, קולנוע ארכיאולוגיה מדע ב. שכל תיבת בשפה ויקימדיה או, מדעי אינו אדריכלות או כדי. עוד בה לשון המלצת בלשנות, ליום מיזם גם זאת. המלצת מונחונים אל צ'ט, גם אחרות מבוקשים ויקיפדיה מלא, ומדעים לעריכה היסטוריה אל קרן. ויש גם מאמר המלחמה משחקים, אם שער בישול ליצירתה, בארגז מיוחדים מה היא. שמות פיסיקה ארץ אם, בקלות ברוכים היא מה.
ערכים ומהימנה דת, מרצועת קצרמרים אם עזה. זאת ספינות ארכיאולוגיה בה, ב החלה ובמתן ביולי לוח. מתוך בישול מדריכים צ'ט אל, בה חשמל המשפט והנדסה רבה, שכל שונה בשפה הבקשה על.

תרבות פיסול מדינות תנך של, או נפלו אתנולוגיה האנציקלופדיה זכר. מלא או מוגש לתרום ממונרכיה, בקר פולנית יוצרים אנגלית דת, דת מיזם צילום מוסיקה שער. פיסול ניווט הבהרה בקר בה, עזה למנוע הראשי לאחרונה של. שתפו ניהול מה שער, על יוני והגולשים צעד, של ויש לציין הגרפים.

על שמו אקטואליה ביוטכנולוגיה, קולנוע ארכיאולוגיה מדע ב. שכל תיבת בשפה ויקימדיה או, מדעי אינו אדריכלות או כדי. עוד בה לשון המלצת בלשנות, ליום מיזם גם זאת. המלצת מונחונים אל צ'ט, גם אחרות מבוקשים ויקיפדיה מלא, ומדעים לעריכה היסטוריה אל קרן. ויש גם מאמר המלחמה משחקים, אם שער בישול ליצירתה, בארגז מיוחדים מה היא. שמות פיסיקה ארץ אם, בקלות ברוכים היא מה.

על שמו אקטואליה ביוטכנולוגיה, קולנוע ארכיאולוגיה מדע ב. שכל תיבת בשפה ויקימדיה או, מדעי אינו אדריכלות או כדי. עוד בה לשון המלצת בלשנות, ליום מיזם גם זאת. המלצת מונחונים אל צ'ט, גם אחרות מבוקשים ויקיפדיה מלא, ומדעים לעריכה היסטוריה אל קרן. ויש גם מאמר המלחמה משחקים, אם שער בישול ליצירתה, בארגז מיוחדים מה היא. שמות פיסיקה ארץ אם, בקלות ברוכים היא מה.ערכים ומהימנה דת, מרצועת קצרמרים אם עזה. זאת ספינות ארכיאולוגיה בה, ב החלה ובמתן ביולי לוח. מתוך בישול מדריכים צ'ט אל, בה חשמל המשפט והנדסה רבה, שכל שונה בשפה הבקשה על.

תרבות פיסול מדינות תנך של, או נפלו אתנולוגיה האנציקלופדיה זכר. מלא או מוגש לתרום ממונרכיה, בקר פולנית יוצרים אנגלית דת, דת מיזם צילום מוסיקה שער. פיסול ניווט הבהרה בקר בה, עזה למנוע הראשי לאחרונה של. שתפו ניהול מה שער, על יוני והגולשים צעד, של ויש לציין הגרפים.

על שמו אקטואליה ביוטכנולוגיה, קולנוע ארכיאולוגיה מדע ב. שכל תיבת בשפה ויקימדיה או, מדעי אינו אדריכלות או כדי. עוד בה לשון המלצת בלשנות, ליום מיזם גם זאת. המלצת מונחונים אל צ'ט, גם אחרות מבוקשים ויקיפדיה מלא, ומדעים לעריכה היסטוריה אל קרן. ויש גם מאמר המלחמה משחקים, אם שער בישול ליצירתה, בארגז מיוחדים מה היא. שמות פיסיקה ארץ אם, בקלות ברוכים היא מה.

על שמו אקטואליה ביוטכנולוגיה, קולנוע ארכיאולוגיה מדע ב. שכל תיבת בשפה ויקימדיה או, מדעי אינו אדריכלות או כדי. עוד בה לשון המלצת בלשנות, ליום מיזם גם זאת. המלצת מונחונים אל צ'ט, גם אחרות מבוקשים ויקיפדיה מלא, ומדעים לעריכה היסטוריה אל קרן. ויש גם מאמר המלחמה משחקים, אם שער בישול ליצירתה, בארגז מיוחדים מה היא. שמות פיסיקה ארץ אם, בקלות ברוכים היא מה.ערכים ומהימנה דת, מרצועת קצרמרים אם עזה. זאת ספינות ארכיאולוגיה בה, ב החלה ובמתן ביולי לוח. מתוך בישול מדריכים צ'ט אל, בה חשמל המשפט והנדסה רבה, שכל שונה בשפה הבקשה על.

תרבות פיסול מדינות תנך של, או נפלו אתנולוגיה האנציקלופדיה זכר. מלא או מוגש לתרום ממונרכיה, בקר פולנית יוצרים אנגלית דת, דת מיזם צילום מוסיקה שער. פיסול ניווט הבהרה בקר בה, עזה למנוע הראשי לאחרונה של. שתפו ניהול מה שער, על יוני והגולשים צעד, של ויש לציין הגרפים.

על שמו אקטואליה ביוטכנולוגיה, קולנוע ארכיאולוגיה מדע ב. שכל תיבת בשפה ויקימדיה או, מדעי אינו אדריכלות או כדי. עוד בה לשון המלצת בלשנות, ליום מיזם גם זאת. המלצת מונחונים אל צ'ט, גם אחרות מבוקשים ויקיפדיה מלא, ומדעים לעריכה היסטוריה אל קרן. ויש גם מאמר המלחמה משחקים, אם שער בישול ליצירתה, בארגז מיוחדים מה היא. שמות פיסיקה ארץ אם, בקלות ברוכים היא מה.

על שמו אקטואליה ביוטכנולוגיה, קולנוע ארכיאולוגיה מדע ב. שכל תיבת בשפה ויקימדיה או, מדעי אינו אדריכלות או כדי. עוד בה לשון המלצת בלשנות, ליום מיזם גם זאת. המלצת מונחונים אל צ'ט, גם אחרות מבוקשים ויקיפדיה מלא, ומדעים לעריכה היסטוריה אל קרן. ויש גם מאמר המלחמה משחקים, אם שער בישול ליצירתה, בארגז מיוחדים מה היא. שמות פיסיקה ארץ אם, בקלות ברוכים היא מה.ערכים ומהימנה דת, מרצועת קצרמרים אם עזה. זאת ספינות ארכיאולוגיה בה, ב החלה ובמתן ביולי לוח. מתוך בישול מדריכים צ'ט אל, בה חשמל המשפט והנדסה רבה, שכל שונה בשפה הבקשה על.

תרבות פיסול מדינות תנך של, או נפלו אתנולוגיה האנציקלופדיה זכר. מלא או מוגש לתרום ממונרכיה, בקר פולנית יוצרים אנגלית דת, דת מיזם צילום מוסיקה שער. פיסול ניווט הבהרה בקר בה, עזה למנוע הראשי לאחרונה של. שתפו ניהול מה שער, על יוני והגולשים צעד, של ויש לציין הגרפים.

על שמו אקטואליה ביוטכנולוגיה, קולנוע ארכיאולוגיה מדע ב. שכל תיבת בשפה ויקימדיה או, מדעי אינו אדריכלות או כדי. עוד בה לשון המלצת בלשנות, ליום מיזם גם זאת. המלצת מונחונים אל צ'ט, גם אחרות מבוקשים ויקיפדיה מלא, ומדעים לעריכה היסטוריה אל קרן. ויש גם מאמר המלחמה משחקים, אם שער בישול ליצירתה, בארגז מיוחדים מה היא. שמות פיסיקה ארץ אם, בקלות ברוכים היא מה.

על שמו אקטואליה ביוטכנולוגיה, קולנוע ארכיאולוגיה מדע ב. שכל תיבת בשפה ויקימדיה או, מדעי אינו אדריכלות או כדי. עוד בה לשון המלצת בלשנות, ליום מיזם גם זאת. המלצת מונחונים אל צ'ט, גם אחרות מבוקשים ויקיפדיה מלא, ומדעים לעריכה היסטוריה אל קרן. ויש גם מאמר המלחמה משחקים, אם שער בישול ליצירתה, בארגז מיוחדים מה היא. שמות פיסיקה ארץ אם, בקלות ברוכים היא מה.
 } 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

XeLaTeX makes this kind of multilingual typesetting ***much*** easier. Note that the only reason for the boxes in place of certain Hebrew characters is, I think, the font I'm using. That is, this is not a general shortcoming of this approach - I just used a font for Hebrew which happened to be on my machine and which may well not be the best choice. Or I might need to enable certain features of the font (see **fontspec**'s documentation), but I don't know anything about Hebrew so I am not in a position to tell.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{polyglossia,fontspec}
\setmainlanguage[variant=british]{english}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont{Noto Sans Hebrew}[Script=Hebrew]
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[L]{left}
\fancyhead[R]{right}

\begin{document}
\Blindtext
\Blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext

\begin{hebrew}
אם לאחרונה לויקיפדיה לרפובליקה אחר, חפש גם דרכה בשפה פיסול. על המחשב מדויקים קרימינולוגיה שכל, זאת ערכים ומהימנה דת, מרצועת קצרמרים אם עזה. זאת ספינות ארכיאולוגיה בה, ב החלה ובמתן ביולי לוח. מתוך בישול מדריכים צ'ט אל, בה חשמל המשפט והנדסה רבה, שכל שונה בשפה הבקשה על.

תרבות פיסול מדינות תנך של, או נפלו אתנולוגיה האנציקלופדיה זכר. מלא או מוגש לתרום ממונרכיה, בקר פולנית יוצרים אנגלית דת, דת מיזם צילום מוסיקה שער. פיסול ניווט הבהרה בקר בה, עזה למנוע הראשי לאחרונה של. שתפו ניהול מה שער, על יוני והגולשים צעד, של ויש לציין הגרפים.

על שמו אקטואליה ביוטכנולוגיה, קולנוע ארכיאולוגיה מדע ב. שכל תיבת בשפה ויקימדיה או, מדעי אינו אדריכלות או כדי. עוד בה לשון המלצת בלשנות, ליום מיזם גם זאת. המלצת מונחונים אל צ'ט, גם אחרות מבוקשים ויקיפדיה מלא, ומדעים לעריכה היסטוריה אל קרן. ויש גם מאמר המלחמה משחקים, אם שער בישול ליצירתה, בארגז מיוחדים מה היא. שמות פיסיקה ארץ אם, בקלות ברוכים היא מה.

על שמו אקטואליה ביוטכנולוגיה, קולנוע ארכיאולוגיה מדע ב. שכל תיבת בשפה ויקימדיה או, מדעי אינו אדריכלות או כדי. עוד בה לשון המלצת בלשנות, ליום מיזם גם זאת. המלצת מונחונים אל צ'ט, גם אחרות מבוקשים ויקיפדיה מלא, ומדעים לעריכה היסטוריה אל קרן. ויש גם מאמר המלחמה משחקים, אם שער בישול ליצירתה, בארגז מיוחדים מה היא. שמות פיסיקה ארץ אם, בקלות ברוכים היא מה.
ערכים ומהימנה דת, מרצועת קצרמרים אם עזה. זאת ספינות ארכיאולוגיה בה, ב החלה ובמתן ביולי לוח. מתוך בישול מדריכים צ'ט אל, בה חשמל המשפט והנדסה רבה, שכל שונה בשפה הבקשה על.

תרבות פיסול מדינות תנך של, או נפלו אתנולוגיה האנציקלופדיה זכר. מלא או מוגש לתרום ממונרכיה, בקר פולנית יוצרים אנגלית דת, דת מיזם צילום מוסיקה שער. פיסול ניווט הבהרה בקר בה, עזה למנוע הראשי לאחרונה של. שתפו ניהול מה שער, על יוני והגולשים צעד, של ויש לציין הגרפים.

על שמו אקטואליה ביוטכנולוגיה, קולנוע ארכיאולוגיה מדע ב. שכל תיבת בשפה ויקימדיה או, מדעי אינו אדריכלות או כדי. עוד בה לשון המלצת בלשנות, ליום מיזם גם זאת. המלצת מונחונים אל צ'ט, גם אחרות מבוקשים ויקיפדיה מלא, ומדעים לעריכה היסטוריה אל קרן. ויש גם מאמר המלחמה משחקים, אם שער בישול ליצירתה, בארגז מיוחדים מה היא. שמות פיסיקה ארץ אם, בקלות ברוכים היא מה.

על שמו אקטואליה ביוטכנולוגיה, קולנוע ארכיאולוגיה מדע ב. שכל תיבת בשפה ויקימדיה או, מדעי אינו אדריכלות או כדי. עוד בה לשון המלצת בלשנות, ליום מיזם גם זאת. המלצת מונחונים אל צ'ט, גם אחרות מבוקשים ויקיפדיה מלא, ומדעים לעריכה היסטוריה אל קרן. ויש גם מאמר המלחמה משחקים, אם שער בישול ליצירתה, בארגז מיוחדים מה היא. שמות פיסיקה ארץ אם, בקלות ברוכים היא מה.ערכים ומהימנה דת, מרצועת קצרמרים אם עזה. זאת ספינות ארכיאולוגיה בה, ב החלה ובמתן ביולי לוח. מתוך בישול מדריכים צ'ט אל, בה חשמל המשפט והנדסה רבה, שכל שונה בשפה הבקשה על.

תרבות פיסול מדינות תנך של, או נפלו אתנולוגיה האנציקלופדיה זכר. מלא או מוגש לתרום ממונרכיה, בקר פולנית יוצרים אנגלית דת, דת מיזם צילום מוסיקה שער. פיסול ניווט הבהרה בקר בה, עזה למנוע הראשי לאחרונה של. שתפו ניהול מה שער, על יוני והגולשים צעד, של ויש לציין הגרפים.

על שמו אקטואליה ביוטכנולוגיה, קולנוע ארכיאולוגיה מדע ב. שכל תיבת בשפה ויקימדיה או, מדעי אינו אדריכלות או כדי. עוד בה לשון המלצת בלשנות, ליום מיזם גם זאת. המלצת מונחונים אל צ'ט, גם אחרות מבוקשים ויקיפדיה מלא, ומדעים לעריכה היסטוריה אל קרן. ויש גם מאמר המלחמה משחקים, אם שער בישול ליצירתה, בארגז מיוחדים מה היא. שמות פיסיקה ארץ אם, בקלות ברוכים היא מה.

על שמו אקטואליה ביוטכנולוגיה, קולנוע ארכיאולוגיה מדע ב. שכל תיבת בשפה ויקימדיה או, מדעי אינו אדריכלות או כדי. עוד בה לשון המלצת בלשנות, ליום מיזם גם זאת. המלצת מונחונים אל צ'ט, גם אחרות מבוקשים ויקיפדיה מלא, ומדעים לעריכה היסטוריה אל קרן. ויש גם מאמר המלחמה משחקים, אם שער בישול ליצירתה, בארגז מיוחדים מה היא. שמות פיסיקה ארץ אם, בקלות ברוכים היא מה.ערכים ומהימנה דת, מרצועת קצרמרים אם עזה. זאת ספינות ארכיאולוגיה בה, ב החלה ובמתן ביולי לוח. מתוך בישול מדריכים צ'ט אל, בה חשמל המשפט והנדסה רבה, שכל שונה בשפה הבקשה על.

תרבות פיסול מדינות תנך של, או נפלו אתנולוגיה האנציקלופדיה זכר. מלא או מוגש לתרום ממונרכיה, בקר פולנית יוצרים אנגלית דת, דת מיזם צילום מוסיקה שער. פיסול ניווט הבהרה בקר בה, עזה למנוע הראשי לאחרונה של. שתפו ניהול מה שער, על יוני והגולשים צעד, של ויש לציין הגרפים.

על שמו אקטואליה ביוטכנולוגיה, קולנוע ארכיאולוגיה מדע ב. שכל תיבת בשפה ויקימדיה או, מדעי אינו אדריכלות או כדי. עוד בה לשון המלצת בלשנות, ליום מיזם גם זאת. המלצת מונחונים אל צ'ט, גם אחרות מבוקשים ויקיפדיה מלא, ומדעים לעריכה היסטוריה אל קרן. ויש גם מאמר המלחמה משחקים, אם שער בישול ליצירתה, בארגז מיוחדים מה היא. שמות פיסיקה ארץ אם, בקלות ברוכים היא מה.

על שמו אקטואליה ביוטכנולוגיה, קולנוע ארכיאולוגיה מדע ב. שכל תיבת בשפה ויקימדיה או, מדעי אינו אדריכלות או כדי. עוד בה לשון המלצת בלשנות, ליום מיזם גם זאת. המלצת מונחונים אל צ'ט, גם אחרות מבוקשים ויקיפדיה מלא, ומדעים לעריכה היסטוריה אל קרן. ויש גם מאמר המלחמה משחקים, אם שער בישול ליצירתה, בארגז מיוחדים מה היא. שמות פיסיקה ארץ אם, בקלות ברוכים היא מה.ערכים ומהימנה דת, מרצועת קצרמרים אם עזה. זאת ספינות ארכיאולוגיה בה, ב החלה ובמתן ביולי לוח. מתוך בישול מדריכים צ'ט אל, בה חשמל המשפט והנדסה רבה, שכל שונה בשפה הבקשה על.

תרבות פיסול מדינות תנך של, או נפלו אתנולוגיה האנציקלופדיה זכר. מלא או מוגש לתרום ממונרכיה, בקר פולנית יוצרים אנגלית דת, דת מיזם צילום מוסיקה שער. פיסול ניווט הבהרה בקר בה, עזה למנוע הראשי לאחרונה של. שתפו ניהול מה שער, על יוני והגולשים צעד, של ויש לציין הגרפים.

על שמו אקטואליה ביוטכנולוגיה, קולנוע ארכיאולוגיה מדע ב. שכל תיבת בשפה ויקימדיה או, מדעי אינו אדריכלות או כדי. עוד בה לשון המלצת בלשנות, ליום מיזם גם זאת. המלצת מונחונים אל צ'ט, גם אחרות מבוקשים ויקיפדיה מלא, ומדעים לעריכה היסטוריה אל קרן. ויש גם מאמר המלחמה משחקים, אם שער בישול ליצירתה, בארגז מיוחדים מה היא. שמות פיסיקה ארץ אם, בקלות ברוכים היא מה.

על שמו אקטואליה ביוטכנולוגיה, קולנוע ארכיאולוגיה מדע ב. שכל תיבת בשפה ויקימדיה או, מדעי אינו אדריכלות או כדי. עוד בה לשון המלצת בלשנות, ליום מיזם גם זאת. המלצת מונחונים אל צ'ט, גם אחרות מבוקשים ויקיפדיה מלא, ומדעים לעריכה היסטוריה אל קרן. ויש גם מאמר המלחמה משחקים, אם שער בישול ליצירתה, בארגז מיוחדים מה היא. שמות פיסיקה ארץ אם, בקלות ברוכים היא מה.
\end{hebrew}
\end{document}
```

[image: Hebrew with English headers]

Comment: Thank you. I know XeLaTeX is preferred sometime, but I have a rather large document, and I fear it will not compile correctly (specifically, converting at this point just to solve this problem will not be preferable). I  was wondering if there is a pdflatex-based solution...

Comment: @yoki It is hard to tell. But you could make a copy and try just changing the preamble. You can define `\L` and `\R` to do nothing or to wrap their arguments in `\begin{hebrew}...\end{hebrew}`. Because *in theory*, you shouldn't have to do much to convert the document. But, in practice, that is not guaranteed. [And probably somebody will provide a pdfLaTeX answer soon enough.]

Comment: This is rather off-topic, but could you tell me if there are issues regarding hyperlinks ('active' cross-references) in XeLaTeX? in Hebrew+Pdflatex this causes issues - and if it should work in XeLaTeX this might be a reason to get into it as you suggest.

Comment: I don't know.  I tried to test but I am not used to adding things in RTL mode in my editor. Can you add an example to your question? **bidi** certainly knows about **hyperref**. You need to load **hyperref** before setting Hebrew as a language (because this loads **bidi**). This strongly suggests it should work, but testing would confirm it.

Comment: @yoki According to **bidi**'s documentation, `The **hyperref** package works fine with bidirectional documents if and only if, your
link will not span more than a line.` See page 17 for further information. So it sounds better than the situation with pdfLaTeX, although it would obviously require a certain amount of care. (If your link is more than a line, it may link a much larger chunk of the document, apparently.)